# How to calculate the mean time between two datetime columns?

Tags: r, datetime, group-by, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean time spent between two columns named started_at and ended_at. Their format is "datetime". I then want to show my results group_by the values of my column named "member_casual". Here is my code so far:

```
# average time cycled by members vs casual riders

time_start <- paste(df$started_at, sep = " ")
time_end <- paste(df$ended_at, sep = " ")
time_trip <- difftime(time_end, time_start, tz = "CST", units = c("mins"))

df %>%
  group_by(member_casual) %>%
  summarise(mean(time_trip))
```

As a result, I get the following:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  member_casual `mean(time_trip)`
  <chr>         <drtn>           
1 casual        9.396873 mins    
2 member        9.396873 mins
```

What should I change to get the two means, one for all the casual riders and one for the members?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide a sample of you data.  Not knowing what the member_casual looks like makes it difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector you are using for calculating means, `time_trip`, is not part of your grouped data.frame. Without having access to any sample data, it's not quite clear what's the deal with `time_start` & `time_end`, but assuming `started_at` & `ended_at` are date-time objects, your pipeline might look something like this:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(time_trip = difftime(ended_at, started_at, units = "mins") %>% 
  group_by(member_casual) %>%
  summarise(mean_time = mean(time_trip))
```

Comment: Thanks margusl! I overly complicated things and I new that. Your code works like a charm.